# When will awaitWorkAvailable resume from runRecomposeAndApplyChanges in Recomposer?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, internals

I saw that changes were tracked and requested invalidation through `Recompoer#runRecomposeAndApplyChanges`. This function tracks changes and requests invalidation in the while statement and remains suspended until new changes are made through `waitWorkAvailable()` in the while statement.

`awaitWorkAvailable()` works with `suspendCancellableCoroutine` and assigns `Continuation` to `workContinuation` if there is no scheduled task. The `workContinuation` is resumed in the invokeOnCompletion of a Job called `effectJob`. Therefore, in order for `workContinuation` to resume, `effectJob` must be completed. `Recomposer#close`, which completes it, is used only in the `withRunningRecomposer` function, but `withRunningRecomposer` is not used.

So where does `workContinuation` resume? I had the same concern a month ago, but I still haven’t solved it.

(Job.cancel is also possible to call invokeOnComplete, but cancel is used only for lifecycle handling through Owner)

#### full-code for

- runRecomposeAndApplyChanges: [cs.android.com](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/tools/dokka-devsite-plugin/+/master:testData/compose/source/androidx/compose/runtime/Recomposer.kt;l=394-492?q=Recomposer.kt)
- awaitWorkAvailable: [cs.android.com](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/tools/dokka-devsite-plugin/+/master:testData/compose/source/androidx/compose/runtime/Recomposer.kt;l=626-638?q=Recomposer.kt)
- effectJob: [cs.android.com](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/tools/dokka-devsite-plugin/+/master:testData/compose/source/androidx/compose/runtime/Recomposer.kt;l=131-169?q=Recomposer.kt)
- close: [cs.android.com](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/tools/dokka-devsite-plugin/+/master:testData/compose/source/androidx/compose/runtime/Recomposer.kt;l=706-712?q=Recomposer.kt)
- withRunningRecomposer: [cs.android.com](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/tools/dokka-devsite-plugin/+/master:testData/compose/source/androidx/compose/runtime/Recomposer.kt;l=61-71?q=Recomposer.kt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it.
A `workContinuation` instance was being returned from `deriveStateLocked()`, and `workContinuation` is resumed whenever invalidation is required thereafter.

```
private fun deriveStateLocked(): CancellableContinuation<Unit>? {
    // ...
    return if (newState == State.PendingWork) {
        workContinuation.also {
            workContinuation = null
        }
    } else null
}
```

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeApi::class)
private suspend fun recompositionRunner(
    block: suspend CoroutineScope.(parentFrameClock: MonotonicFrameClock) -> Unit
) {
    val parentFrameClock = coroutineContext.monotonicFrameClock
    withContext(broadcastFrameClock) {
        val callingJob = coroutineContext.job
        registerRunnerJob(callingJob)

        val unregisterApplyObserver = Snapshot.registerApplyObserver { changed, _ ->
            synchronized(stateLock) {
                if (_state.value >= State.Idle) {
                    snapshotInvalidations += changed
                    deriveStateLocked()
                } else null
            }?.resume(Unit)
        }
    // ...
}

internal override fun invalidate(composition: ControlledComposition) {
    synchronized(stateLock) {
        if (composition !in compositionInvalidations) {
            compositionInvalidations += composition
            deriveStateLocked()
        } else null
    }?.resume(Unit)
}

internal override fun invalidateScope(scope: RecomposeScopeImpl) {
    synchronized(stateLock) {
        snapshotInvalidations += setOf(scope)
        deriveStateLocked()
    }?.resume(Unit)
}

// ... more invalidation methods are using deriveStateLocked().
```